# 2 navbar-collapse в ряд

Tags: bootstrap

расположил 2 `navbar-collapse` в ряд с помощью `float:left;`
При свернутом меню не корректно работает переход с одного `открытого` списка на другой , подскажите как наиболее просто решить проблему .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Пример</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  
  #navbar-collapse-links {
    float: left;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-account">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-links">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-links">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Action1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Action2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Action3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-account">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
<script>
  
  $('#navbar-collapse-links').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#navbar-collapse-account').collapse("hide");
  })
  $('#navbar-collapse-account').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#navbar-collapse-links').collapse("hide");
  })
  
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  })
  
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Можно у кнопок убрать `data-toggle="collapse"` и назначить им обработчик onClick, где сначала сворачивать "соседнее" меню и разворачивать собственное

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov сделайте ответом свой комментарий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно у кнопок убрать `data-toggle="collapse"` и назначить им обработчик onClick, где сначала сворачивать "соседнее" меню и разворачивать собственное

Comment: Запутался с событиями в скриптах  , переопределил свойства в медиа  - вроде всё работает правильно , спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

В итоге остановился на следующем решении

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Пример</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  
  #navbar-collapse-links {
    float: left;
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
  #navbar-collapse-links {
    float: none;
  }  
  }
  
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-account">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-links">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-links">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Action1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Action2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Action3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-account">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
<script>

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  })
  
</script>

</html>
```